# Get attribute of element in var with multiple html elements js/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, frontend

I have a `div` with multiple `a` elements.

```
    <div class="vertical-menu">
        <a href="#" data-actiontime="0" class="listItemActive">
        <strong class="time">00:00</strong> || <strong class="action">Action x</strong>
        </a>
        <a href="#" data-actiontime="36" >
        <strong class="time">00:36</strong> || <strong class="action">Action y</strong>
        </a>
</div>
```

Each `a` calls the function `myClickHandler` when clicked.

For example when clicked in 1'st `a`:

```
function myClickHandler(evt)
{

    evt.preventDefault();

    var elemReceived, attrValue, aElem;

    elemReceived = evt.currentTarget;

    console.log(elemReceived); //it outputs the "a" with the childs elements "strong" ... ok
    aElem = $(elemReceived).find('a'); //get only the "a" element
    console.log(aElem); //it outputs "w.fn.init [prevObject: w.fn.init(1)]length: 0prevObject: w.fn.init [a.listItemActive]__proto__: Object(0)

    attrValue =  $(aElem).attr("data-actiontime"); //alse tried with: aElem.getAttribute("data-actiontime"); but still not working
    console.log(attrValue); //it outputs "undefined"!!!!

globalVarY = attrValue ;
        aElem.setAttribute("class", "listItemActive");

    }
```

How can this be solved?

---

Edit 1:

```
function setListItemClickBehaviour()
{
    var aElements;

    aElements = document.querySelectorAll(".vertical-menu a");
                aElements.forEach(function (aElements)
                {
                    aElements.addEventListener("click", myClickHandler);
                });

}//setListItemClickBehaviour
```

Comment: How are you binding the click event handlers to the `a` elements?

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your goal. You can identify the specific element using event.target and you can identify the parent element with event.parentNode

Comment: see my edit please @Martin

Comment: You can also bind a single event listener to `document.querySelector(".vertical-menu")` and get the right `a` element by checking `evt.target.matches("a")`, then getting `evt.target`. `.find('a')` will probably not be what you’re looking for.

Comment: That only works if the click is in any chlid of the "a" ...if the click occurs in an empty zone of the "a" element it will target the "a" parent, wich i dont want @Andrew

Comment: You're asking "How can this be solved?" yet you never really described the problem. I don't know what you're trying to fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read the attribute like I'm showing you in the code snippet below:

```js
function myClickHandler(evt) {
  console.log(this.getAttribute('data-actiontime'));
}

function setListItemClickBehaviour() {
  var aElements = document.querySelectorAll(".vertical-menu a");
  aElements.forEach(function(aElements) {
    aElements.addEventListener("click", myClickHandler);
  });

}

setListItemClickBehaviour();
```

```html
<div class="vertical-menu">
  <a href="#" data-actiontime="0" class="listItemActive">
    <strong class="time">00:00</strong> || <strong class="action">Action x</strong>
  </a>
  <br />
  <a href="#" data-actiontime="36">
    <strong class="time">00:36</strong> || <strong class="action">Action y</strong>
  </a>
</div>
```